# Select entries from TABLE A based on TABLE B pyspark

Tags: python, sql, pyspark

In SQL we are able to select entries from a TABLE A based on a column in TABLE B.

Please see below:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE A 
WHERE NAME in (SELECT NAME FROM TABLE B)
```

How do I replicate this piece of code in pyspark without using a sql context?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PySpark: match the values of a DataFrame column against another DataFrame column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42545788/pyspark-match-the-values-of-a-dataframe-column-against-another-dataframe-column)

Answer (score 0):

`Df=A.join(B, on =['Name'], how ='inner' ).select(A.columns)`

Comment: This question is about Pyspark, not about Pandas

Comment: It's a pyspark code , please check  the documentation - https://dzone.com/articles/pyspark-join-explained-with-examples

Comment: yep, you have now changed your answer to use the Spark syntax